# Strange behavior from a while loop

Tags: java, multithreading, compiler-optimization

So I'm writing a video playback library, the details aren't important. What's going on is this bit of code needs to run at the end of the run() method of the decoder thread:

```
System.out.println("Video decoding complete");
int a = 0, b = 0;
do
{
    a = pictures.getCount();
    b = samples.getCount();
}while(a > 0 || b > 0);
Gdx.app.log("Status", videoPath + " completed playing successfully.");
videoComplete = true;
```

The problem is, anything passed the do{}while doesn't execute. Here's the weird part, this bit of code executes when the System.out.println is added in the while loop:

```
System.out.println("Video decoding complete");
int a = 0, b = 0;
do
{
    System.out.println("Waiting for packets to drain.");
    a = pictures.getCount();
    b = samples.getCount();
}while(a > 0 || b > 0);
Gdx.app.log("Status", videoPath + " completed playing successfully.");
videoComplete = true;
```

I suspect that the compiler knows I'm trying to get it to run a loop doing nothing for a bit, and it just snips out the code or something. But really I have no idea what's happening. If someone knows better than I, I'd love to have a better solution. Such a simple thing that I'm hung up on here!

Comment: No, the compiler never removes bits of code when it changes the behaviour of the program. How do you know that they aren't executed ?

Comment: Why would you want to "get it to run a loop doing nothing" in the first place?

Comment: I don't know the reason for what you're seeing, but what you have there is a "busy wait" that will chew CPU until the counts reach zero. Read up on thread synchronisation, and make it wait() for the other thread(s).

Comment: Post a complete example where we can reproduce, else it's hard to debug.

Comment: @slim - Yes, good call. The answer below worked, but I ended up taking your advice. :D

Comment: @slim, see my fix below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this as per @slim's advice:

```
                System.out.println("Video decoding complete");
                this.decoderComplete = true;
                //wait until notified that packets are done draining
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        videoComplete = true;
                        this.container.close();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Gdx.app.log("Status", videoPath + " completed playing successfully.");
                videoComplete = true;
                this.container.close();
```

And in the other thread, once we know we're done reading all the packets:

```
if(this.packetHandlerRunnable.getNumAudioPackets() <= 0 
                && this.packetHandlerRunnable.getNumVideoPackets() <= 0 
                && this.packetHandlerRunnable.isDecoderComplete())
        {
            synchronized(packetHandlerRunnable)
            {
                this.packetHandlerRunnable.notify();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is worth remembering that wait/notify is not a reliable signal. The wait must be in a loop which checkes a state set in the code with the notify. If you don't do this a)the notify can be lost or b) the wait finishes spuriously.

Comment: Also you still need to check the variable within a synchronized block to avoid the issue in the question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - so the decoder thread can close up the objects it's using. There are JNI libs in there that must be cleaned up manually. Good question though.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input! It's been enlightening :D

Comment: it would give you a variable for the waiter to check in its loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - The idea is to call wait to avoid chewing up the CPU in my run() method. If I had more time I would benchmark the two solutions to see who's is best, but alas, it is out of scope right now :p

Comment: Although if you're feeling up to it, feel free to test out both solutions out. This code is open source:

https://github.com/seannybgoode/libGDX-EvolveLiteMediaPlayerLibrary

This code isn't live yet, but it will be sometime in the next few hours.

Comment: I got that. I was pointing out that unless you fix the code it won't always work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Are you sure that wait() is unreliable? It seems like some improvements were made back in Java 5. Is it possible that there have been further improvements since then? I'm not having any trouble with the wait() notify() system.

Comment: wait () works are documented. The problem with multi-threading bugs is that your program can happen to work but a small thing like the OS, the version of Java, the processor used or an apparently unrelated line of code and it suddenly breaks.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that pictures.getCount() and samples.getCount() read non-`volatile` fields.  When you only read a non-volatile field it can be inlined for performance reasons, however if you do something like call a `synchronized` method (And System.out is synchronized) it doesn't optimise the code this way and has to perform the look up each time.

I suggest you try adding an empty synchronized block and see if this still works, i.e. do this instead of the println

```
synchronized(this) { }
```

Comment: Why should adding `System.out.println("Waiting for packets to drain.");` make any difference?

Comment: Possibly by adding a tiny pause while the IO happens, during which the non-volatile fields get propagated.

Comment: Let me give it a shot and try it out. I've been avoiding using synchronized because of the way it messes with my openGL thread, but I think this should be safe. You're right about the non-volatile field thing, and the openGL havoc is the reason for that.

Comment: @pbabcdefp like I said, when the code contains a synchronized method it guarantees viability of fields and prevents such optimisations.

Comment: @slim the pause matters if the code doesn't reach 10K iterations. Once it reaches 10K iterations it won't be compiled and thus not optimised. After 10K iterations it might be more heavily optimised.

Comment: @ScubaSteve an alternative is to read a dummy volatile field of your own.

Comment: You didn't say anything in your answer about why the `println` makes a difference. I'm just interested to understand why the calls are apparently not inlined with the `println` there.

Comment: @pbabcdefp println is a method on System.out it does matter whether it is in lined or not. What matters is it performs an operation which prevents certain optimisations.

Comment: But why does `println` prevent the optimizations?

Comment: Apologies. I've just realised you did address that in your answer (+1). It's late.

Comment: This worked great, and behaved as expected, but I didn't end up using it because of someone's comment above, will post below what I ended up doing.

Comment: @ScubaSteve adding a `Thread.sleep (5);` is likely to be a better option as it avoids wasting CPU.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Yes I had considered, that. The problem with your suggestion is that I can't know how long the thread needs to sleep for. It may take some time for the other process to finish with the data. See my answer above.